# NSURL POST with XSS vulnerability for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, xss, nsurl

I ran into a problem with my code after the company did a code scan.
The report showed that my code, where I try to do a web service POST request, has a vulnerability for XSS attacks.
I'm not very familiar with issues on security.
Can anyone point me at the right direction as to how to fix this security vulnerability?

Thanks alot.

My web service calls are to a CA trusted server, so I used:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
    SecTrustResultType result;
    SecTrustEvaluate(challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust, & result);

    if(result == kSecTrustResultProceed ||  result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified) {
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge];
        return;
```

to secure the connection.
The following code is where I compose my URL request.

Again, I don't have a lot of knowledge on the topic of security, 
so any help would be appreciated!

```
- (BOOL)httpPostWithUrl:(NSString *)url headersAndValues:(NSDictionary *)headersAndValues delegate:(id)delegate
{
    NSMutableString *bodyString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    for (NSString *key in [headersAndValues allKeys])
    {
        [bodyString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&", key, headersAndValues[key]]];
    }

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                          timeoutInterval:20.0f];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    if (bodyString.length)
    {
        NSString *requestBody = [bodyString substringToIndex:bodyString.length-1];
        NSData *requestData = [requestBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

        if (!_connectionRunning)
        {
            NSURLConnection *connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
           // error
        }
    }
}
return NO;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think that xss in this line:

```
[bodyString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&", key, headersAndValues[key]]];
```

You need to check key and headersAndValues[key] on invalid characters.

```
NSString *checkedKey = [self alphanumericStringFromString:checkedKey];

+ (NSString *)alphanumericString { // NSString category
    NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    NSString *trimmedReplacement = [[self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return trimmedReplacement;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! but what are invalid characters? Anything you don't expect from an url link?

Comment: Yes. These symbols can interrupt correct work of operation. If your parameters are executable code and they added to the code page, they can be executed. For example: value = "<script>alert('attacked')</script>".  Most used it : & and ? (- can add new parameters;), " and ' , < (html tag),  \ (escape character).